# Configure gud to invoke python3 debugger instead of python debugger

Tags: python, debugging, gud

When I issue the Emacs command `M-x pdb` it invokes Python’s `pdb` as `python -m pdb foo.py`. I want to instead invoke `python3 -m pdb foo.py` -- how do I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in emacs 27, this is controlled by the customization `gud_pdb_command_name`.

The easy way to set it is to invoke `pdb` once, to get past any autoload issues, then `M-x customize_option` `gud_pdb_command_name` then fill in the command desired and choose `Apply` to try it out or `Apply and Save` to have it stored for future use.

Comment: Does "Apply and Save" store it in `.emacs`? I assume there is some magic incantation I can put in `.emacs`.

Comment: I have no `pdb` program which emacs complains about, but I can do `python3 -m pdb foo.py` from the command line.

Comment: So you have a couple of choices, write a `pdb` shell script, something like `#!/bin/sh\nexec python3 -m pdb "$@"\n` would do it, or else customize the variable to be `python3 -m pdb`. Yes "Apply and Save" does store it in your emacs startup files, which might be ~/.emacs, ~/.emacs.d/init.el, ~/.config/emacs/init.el or somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just threw `(setq gud-pdb-command-name "python3 -m pdb")` in my `.emacs` file and all is good.

Comment: @wcochran, as you suggested, I was able to run the python3 -m pdb with my script in emacs. But it will not give me 2 separate windows, 1st  is the command window, and the 2nd is source code window where I can see the pointer on current execution line. The default pdb does that. Any comments ?

Comment: @user3595231 Are you able to switch to the other buffers with M-x b ? If so you can set the windows up yourself by splitting the screen (M-x 2) and then switch to the desired buffer.

Comment: @wcocharn, please see my posting under,  if I was to split the window into 2 by the "M-x 
 2" command , I don't  get such behavior.